# Compare and assign value in Python list

Tags: python

I've two lists as

```
[name1, email1, name2, email2, name3, email3, name4, email4]
[name5, name5, name7]
```

I need to check if the emails are present or not and if present assign them as **name** and **email** respectively, else assign the names to **name** and leave the **email** field blank. The **name** and **email** in this case are of strict format. So i've used `@` operator to define if it's in email or not.

Here is my code :

```
for i in range(0,len(mylist)):
    if '@' in mylist[i]:
        name = mylist[i-1]
        email = mylist[i]
    else:
        email = ''
        name = mylist[i]

    print name
    print email
```

The problem with this code is if it sees the email it works perfectly fine, but for the name field it places the email to be blank. Is there anyway to do this in Python ?

Comment: Didn't you want the email field to be blank?

Comment: How are you distinguishing a name from an email in the list?

Comment: (i) You don't need `range()` for iterating a list, it's iterable already. (ii) You can also use a better data format for this like [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) or [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) or [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). (iii) Your indentation was wrong, I've corrected it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The emails and name in this case are strictly of the same format , so i'm using simple logic, if it has @ operator , it is email or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what is mylist, but I'll assume it's the list of emails and you're running through its values to check if email is there (?)

Since your list starts with name, you'll need to check for i+1 instead and check if mylist has the index i+1. If you find it, you'll then increase i 2 times, to prevent the name from being parsed alone - so use a while instead.

```
i = 0
while i < len(mylist):
    if i + 1 < len(mylist) and '@' in mylist[i+1]:
        name = mylist[i]
        email = mylist[i+1]
        i+=1
    else:
        email = ''
        name = mylist[i]

    print(name)
    print(email)
    i+=1
```

Comment: I'm using a very simple but effective (in my case) to detect email. I'm just using @ to determine if it's an email or not . If @ is present in the string , it's email

Comment: mylist can have anyone of the given lists

Comment: I've seen the edit. Please explain this: "The problem with this code is if it sees the email it works perfectly fine, but for the name field it places the email to be blank. Is there anyway to do this in Python ?"

Comment: while looping , since the name field does not have '@' operator , it sets the email to blank in this case, even thought the name has email field. As it sees the @ it sets email field it then again sets email field and name field .

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, x in enumerate(mylist):
    if '@' in x and i > 0:
        name = mylist[i-1]
        email = x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider putting your data into a dictionary where the name is automatically linked to the email, if it exists. Here I have changed your original list to reflect the '@' in your email addresses.

```
mylist = ['name1', 'email@1', 'name2', 'email@2', 'name3', 'email@3', 'name4', 'email@4', 'name5', 'name6']
i = 0
name_email = {}
while i < len(mylist):
    if (i+1) != len(mylist) and '@' in mylist[i+1]:
        name_email[mylist[i]] = mylist[i+1]
        i += 1
    else:
        name_email[mylist[i]] = ""
    i += 1

print(name_email)  

output:
{'name1': 'email@1', 'name5': '', 'name2': 'email@2', 'name3': 'email@3', 'name6': '', 'name4': 'email@4'}
```